# Ignore line break while parsing JSON

Tags: java, json, jettison

I am using `Jettison` in Java for parsing `JSON` messages, But in some cases `JSON` contains line break in values hence getting exception.

```
{
  "errors": {
    "error": [
      {
        "error-message": "values are not unique: 121
/adduser/userid
/adduser/userid",
        "error-urlpath": "/adduser/userid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any way to ignore line break in values while parsing error message in Java?

Thanks.

Comment: It's just not valid JSON - what's creating this JSON? You should really try to fix that instead. If it's broken for line breaks, it may well fail to escape other things...

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the JSON source as it is invalid (like Jon Skeet posted).
The other way (not so elegant) would be to replace all line breaks with "" or " " and try to parse after that.